# Yahoo analytics isn't registering all my pages

Tags: javascript, html, analytics, yahoo, yahoo-analytics

This is how I set the test up. I made a site with 5 pages, namely "Home", "Sub page 1"->"Sub page 3" and "About". On all of them I have the exact same code:

```
<!-- Yahoo! Web Analytics - All rights reserved -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://d.yimg.com/mi/eu/ywa.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    /*globals YWA*/
    var YWATracker = YWA.getTracker("*************");
    YWATracker.setDocumentName("Home");
    YWATracker.setDocumentGroup("Top level pages");
    YWATracker.submit();
</script>
<noscript>
    <div>
        <img src="http://s.analytics.yahoo.com/p.pl?a=*************&amp;js=no" width="1" height="1" alt="" />
    </div>
</noscript>
```

Although of course, all 5 pages have an identical value in `setDocumentName()`, namely "Home", "Subpage1", "Subpage2", "Subpage3" and "About".

Now how come all the visits to the subpages are logged as "Home" in the "Entries by Title" report? Even though I browsed the site evenly through all the pages, my report says something like:

```
Home: 67
About: 21
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I think its best not to set the document name explicitly. The analytics code should automatically use the default page url.

Comment: I supposed it would use the page Title, which is identical in all pages. That's why I set a unique name for each document. It doesn't matter though, right? :)

Comment: I use google analytics and usually there is a delay of upto 24 hours for new visits to be reflected in the stats. I don't know if this is the case for you :)

Comment: Yahoo analytics updates statistics live. I see no good reason why it only registers "Home" and "About".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Entries by Title" report shows the original entry page the user started the *visit* on, for the duration of a *visit*.  So if you for instance go to "home" and then leave and then come back to for instance "subpage2" (be it an external site or some page on your site that is not tagged with YWA code), and it's still within the same visit, it will count the hit for "home" because that was the entry page for the visit (read up on YWA's definition of a visit).